# Testing the Tabs and Tab components

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

While updating pure functions with the new React 16.6 decorator `memo()`, we found that the Navigation menu was broken, because material-ui handles props within the Tabs component, which my wrapper NavigationTabs isn't aware of.

In order to spot this kind of error in the future, we're trying to consolidate our test suite by making sure that if clicking on a tab, then updating the component, the new properties (eg selected=True) will be set as expected.

Unfortunately, we couldn't get his working. Please find our code below:

**Menu Component**

```ts
import React, {FC} from "react";
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import history from "~/history";
import {MINISITE_TABS} from "~/constants";
import "./style.less";

const NavigationTabs: FC = () => (
  <Tabs
    className="minisite-navigation"
    onChange={(event, tablink) => history.push(tablink)}
    value={history.location.pathname}
  >
    {MINISITE_TABS.map(item => (
      <Tab
        label={item.label}
        value={item.link}
        key={item.label}
        disableRipple
      />
    ))}
  </Tabs>
);

export default NavigationTabs;
```

**Test**

```js
import React from "react";
import {shallow} from "enzyme";
import history from "~/history";
import NavigationTabs from "../NavigationTabs";

describe("NavigationTabs Component", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<NavigationTabs />).dive();

  it("shows 4 tabs Navigation", () => {
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();

    expect(wrapper.find("WithStyles(Tab)")).toHaveLength(4);
  });

  it("should change the page when a tab is clicked upon", () => {
    let tab = wrapper
      .dive()
      .find("WithStyles(Tab)")
      .first();
    expect(tab.prop("selected")).toBeFalsy();

    tab.simulate("click");
    wrapper.find("Tabs").simulate("change", {}, "/story/tab1");
    wrapper.update();
    expect(history.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith("/story/tab1");

    tab = wrapper
      .dive()
      .find("WithStyles(Tab)")
      .first();
    expect(tab.prop("selected")).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**Error**

```
NavigationTabs Component
    ✓ shows 4 tabs Navigation (12ms)
    ✕ should change the page when a tab is clicked upon (14ms)                                              

  ● NavigationTabs Component › should change the page when a tab is clicked upon                            

    expect(received).toBeTruthy()

    Received: false

      29 |       .find("WithStyles(Tab)")
      30 |       .first();
    > 31 |     expect(tab.prop("selected")).toBeTruthy();                                                   
         |                                  ^
      32 |   });
      33 | });
      34 | 

      at Object.toBeTruthy (src/components/pages/MiniSite/Navigation/__tests__/NavigationTabs-test.js:31:34)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        1.968s, estimated 2s
Ran all test suites matching /NavigationTabs/i.
```

Versions:

- React 16.6.3
- Enzyme 3.7.0
- Jest 23.6.0
- Material-ui 3.1.2

How would you go about testing this scenario ?

Comment: Hey! Did you find the answer? I'm struggling with it